# Is marking as duplicate or flagging appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652665/alert-messages-for-lua-functions/33655587) was asked the other day.

I answered it (with a rusty C macro that I wrote in the edit box, and mentioned as much in my answer).

The answer was correct but contained a "typo" in the use of the macro version of the answer.

A (now deleted I assume since I can't find it) follow-up question was asked (I believe by the same author though I clearly can't be sure) in which an answerer indicated that I had made the typo in my use of the macro.

Seeing that correction I went back and corrected my original answer.

Today [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672963/how-to-use-macro-in-lua) (which as I indicated in my comment feels **awfully** like the question I can no longer find) asks for help getting the *original* (incorrect) macro usage of my answer working.

A helpful user answers the question and again indicates my C error.

I then added [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672963/how-to-use-macro-in-lua?noredirect=1#comment55119132_33672963) indicating that the updated answer on the (linked) original question has the corrected usage.

The OP acknowledges that they failed to see the update to my original answer.

Is leaving the current question open (and encouraging the answer to be accepted) the correct course of action?

Is marking it as duplicate and hoping it gets enough votes correct?

Should I flag it as duplicate for moderator attention (since the other necessary votes may not come? (Is that an appropriate use of a flag?)

Comment: My thoughts on your _actual_ point: I would close as duplicate, since really your answer is what the OP of the new question needed. That said, I don't know if that's really the recommended course here... If it's not, the "typo" reason really should fit the new question as well, since it was just a typo in your answer that caused the issue.

Comment: @Kendra Agreed. There are a number of possible ways to make missing the update entirely reasonable (stale tab among them). I should probably remove that parenthetical from this question. It doesn't help to speculate on that. The main question is really whether I should vote to close as duplicate or flag to close as duplicate (i.e. does waiting for other votes, which may or may not come, make sense or not).